# Display Result of Calculation in SQL in 2 decimal places

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, select, decimal

I wrote a simple query to find the percentage of two columns but I will like the result in a column with only two decimal places. This is what I wrote but I am getting error and I can't seem to be able to fix it.

```
SELECT 
    Small_Bags,
    Total_Bags,
    (Small_Bags / Total_Bags) * 100 AS Small_Bags_Percent
    (Select CAST (Small_Bags_Percent AS DECIMAL (10,2)))
FROM Table_Bags
WHERE Total_Bags <>0
```

Comment: If you get an error, tell us what the error is

Comment: Mysql <> sql server, what are you really using?

Comment: I was using BigQuery
Many thanks! I got it resolved.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use your column alias on same query. You can do this.

```
select Small_Bags
    , Total_Bags
    , (Small_Bags / Total_Bags) * 100 AS Small_Bags_Percent
    , cast(((Small_Bags / Total_Bags) * 100) as decimal(10,2))
from Table_Bags
where Total_Bags > 0
```

or use subquery

```
select t1.Small_Bags, t1.Total_Bags, t1.Small_Bags_Percent
    , cast(t1.Small_Bags_Percent as decimal(10,2))
from 
    (select Small_Bags
        , Total_Bags
        , (Small_Bags / Total_Bags) * 100 AS Small_Bags_Percent
        , cast(((Small_Bags / Total_Bags) * 100) as decimal(10,2))
    from Table_Bags
    where Total_Bags > 0) t1
```

Answer (score 1):

Two functions:

```
 SELECT ROUND(12345.678, 2), FORMAT(12345.678, 2);
+---------------------+----------------------+
| ROUND(12345.678, 2) | FORMAT(12345.678, 2) |
+---------------------+----------------------+
|            12345.68 | 12,345.68            |
+---------------------+----------------------+
```

Note that one of them also adds "thousands-separators".

(Also, there is no need for a subquery.)

Answer (score 0):

If this is MySQL, I can see about 3 possible cause of error from the query.

1. There's no comma after `Small_Bags_Percent`.
2. `CAST ( ...` shouldn't have a space in between the opening parenthesis so it suppose to be `CAST( ...`.
3. Wrong way of selecting `Small_Bags_Percent`. It's possible when doing it like so:

```
SELECT 
  Small_Bags,
  Total_Bags,
  (Small_Bags / Total_Bags) * 100 AS Small_Bags_Percent,
  CAST(((SELECT Small_Bags_Percent)) AS DECIMAL (10,2))
FROM Table_Bags
WHERE Total_Bags <>0
```

But, if you have no reason to have two `Small_Bags_Percent` columns, why don't just directly `CAST()` onto the first one?

```
SELECT 
  Small_Bags,
  Total_Bags,
  CAST((Small_Bags / Total_Bags) * 100 AS DECIMAL (10,2)) AS Small_Bags_Percent
FROM Table_Bags
WHERE Total_Bags <>0
```